# Stress in the question Do you want some coffee?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent, word-stress

when we pronounce the question: "Do you want some coffee?" we usually only stress the words "want" and "coffee". Am I right? As far as I know the determiner "some" is unstressed as long as the stress is not shifted for special emphasis. Am I right? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. You would only stress "some" if it was the most important part of the question - "Do you want **some** coffee or **a lot of** coffee? In that case, "coffee" would be unstressed.